# Convert column data type (char) from a dataset and make new column with date format

Tags: r

```
ride_id          rideable_type started_at      ended_at        member…¹
  <chr>            <chr>         <chr>           <chr>           <chr>   
1 C2F7DD78E82EC875 electric_bike 1/13/2022 11:59 1/13/2022 12:02 casual  
2 A6CF8980A652D272 electric_bike 1/10/2022 8:41  1/10/2022 8:46  casual  
3 BD0F91DFF741C66D classic_bike  1/25/2022 4:53  1/25/2022 4:58  member  
4 CBB80ED419105406 classic_bike  1/4/2022 0:18   1/4/2022 0:33   casual  
5 DDC963BFDDA51EEA classic_bike  1/20/2022 1:31  1/20/2022 1:37  member  
6 A39C6F6CC0586C0B classic_bike  1/11/2022 18:48 1/11/2022 18:51 member
```

dataset name is AllData , i want to convert column started_at into date format , extract Day,month and hours into new column in same dataset

I tried as.date function to convert the whole column but it did't work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `readr::parse_date()` will make that conversion for you